# How to add class active on specific li on user click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have a menu with certain items and I want when a user `clicks` on any `li` than only its class becomes `active`. I have a menu items like following:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="dropdown active">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlHome" runat="server" href="Default.aspx">Home</asp:HyperLink>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <asp:HyperLink runat="Server" cssClass="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="0" data-close-others="false" href="#">
            Register
            <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
        </asp:HyperLink>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hlCreateAccount" href="register.aspx">Create Account</asp:HyperLink></li>
            <li><asp:HyperLink runat="Server" href="forgot.aspx" ID="hlForgot">Forgot Credentials ?</asp:HyperLink></li>
            <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" href="blocked.aspx" ID="hlBlockedAccount">Blocked Account</asp:HyperLink></li>
            <li><asp:HyperLink ID="hlUnblockAccount" href="unblock.aspx" runat="server">Unblock Account</asp:HyperLink></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink  ID="hlBug" runat="server" href="bug.aspx">Report A Bug</asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="hlContact" runat="server" href="contact.aspx">Contact Us</asp:HyperLink></li>
</ul>
```

And I have tried the following code with jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        var loc = window.location.href.split('/');
        var page = loc[loc.length - 1];
        $('ul.nav a').each(function (i) {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            if (href.indexOf(page) !== -1) {
                $('ul.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

It's not working with the drop-down menus while working perfectly with all other menus not having drop-down items. How can I change the code that it works too with menu items having a drop-down list of items? I am also using the update panel on my page.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You specified both jQuery and Javascript in the tags so here's both approaches.

**jQuery**

```
var selector = '.nav li';

$(selector).on('click', function(){
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bvf9u/

---

**Pure Javascript:**

```
var selector, elems, makeActive;

selector = '.nav li';

elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

makeActive = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
        elems[i].classList.remove('active');

    this.classList.add('active');
};

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
    elems[i].addEventListener('mousedown', makeActive);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rn3nc/1

---

**jQuery with event delegation:**

Please note that in approach 1, the handler is directly bound to that element. If you're expecting the DOM to update and new `li`s to be injected, it's better to use event delegation and delegate to the next element that will remain static, in this case the `.nav`:

```
$('.nav').on('click', 'li', function(){
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bvf9u/1/

The subtle difference is that the handler is bound to the `.nav` now, so when you click the `li` the event *bubbles* up the DOM to the `.nav` which invokes the handler if the element clicked matches your `selector` argument. This means new elements won't need a new handler bound to them, because it's already bound to an ancestor.

It's really quite interesting. Read more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I am using update panel in my page, your suggestion is not working. Would you please tell me how can i get this to be done with update panel.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, do you have development version online somewhere? Have you tried the pure JS version I just posted?

Comment: yes i have tried that but it does not works with update panel .

Comment: It's just plain old Javascript, your choice of backend framework shouldn't matter. I'm afraid I'd need to see it in action to help any more.

Comment: Thankyou but I cant show you I do not have version online. Plus I hae tried this before with update panel which is ajax control in asp.net this was working perfect but when I added sub items in li it was not working in dropdown case.

Comment: If you're using AJAX to update the DOM, you're probably in need of event delegation, check approach 3 and my notes. Also play with the fiddles and read the jQuery docs to understand more what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dates li a').click(function (e) {

        $('.dates li a').removeClass('active');

        var $parent = $(this);
        if (!$parent.hasClass('active')) {
            $parent.addClass('active');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

//Write a javascript method to bind click event of each "li" item

```
    function BindClickEvent()
    {
    var selector = '.nav li';
    //Removes click event of each li
    $(selector ).unbind('click');
    //Add click event
    $(selector ).bind('click', function()
    {
        $(selector).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    }
```

//first call this method when first time when page load

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
         BindClickEvent();
    });
```

//Call BindClickEvent method  from server side

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page,GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),"BindClickEvent();",true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off topic but having arrived here while developing an Angular2 app I would like to share that Angular2 automatically adds the class "router-link-active" to active router links such as this one:

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['Dashboard']">Dashboard</a></li>
```

You can therefore easily style such links using CSS:

```css
.router-link-active {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Remove active for all items.
        $('.sidebar-menu li').removeClass('active');
        // highlight submenu item
        $('li a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
        // Highlight parent menu item.
        $('ul a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parents('li').addClass('active')
```

Comment: Describe the changes you made or specify where to replace this code