# css menu, making picture move with current page

Tags: html, css

```
    <div class="container">
            <div class="content">

                <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="current">Movies</a>
                        <ul class="subs">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Thriller</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Comedy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Romance</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">TV Shows</a>
                        <ul class="subs">
                            <li><a href="html/walkingdead.html">The Walking Dead</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Grimm</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Supernatural</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Scrubs</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Donation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Follow</a>
                        <ul class="subs">
                            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/newcriticalratings?ref=hl">Facebook</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://criticalratings.tumblr.com/">Tumblr</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
```

css:

```
ul#nav {
color: #232223;
display:block;
position: relative;
top:-53px;
left: 5%; 
font: 16px/26px HELVETICA,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
-webkit-animation:opa 6s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-moz-animation:opa 6s;
animation:opa 6s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
z-index: 2;
}
ul#nav,ul#nav ul {
list-style:none;
}
ul#nav .subs {
background-color: rgba(121,160,160,0.8);
border:1px solid #887963;
display:none;
float:left;
left:0;
padding:10px;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
z-index: 2;
}
ul#nav li:hover>* {
display:block;
}
ul#nav li:hover {
position:relative;
z-index: 2;
}
ul#nav ul .subs {
left:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
z-index: 2;
}
ul#nav ul {
padding:0 5px 5px;
}
ul#nav li {
display:inline;
float:left;
z-index: 2;
}
ul#nav a {
color: #353435;
float: left;
font-size: 15px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
line-height: 14px;
min-width:60px;
padding: 60px 20px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #B4C6C6;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul#nav > li:hover > a {
border-top: 5px solid #887963;
color: #1e1e1e;
padding-top: 55px;
}
ul#nav li a.current, ul#nav li a.current:hover {
background: url("../nav_current.png") no-repeat scroll center top     transparent;
border: medium none;
color: #fff;
padding-top: 60px;
text-shadow: none;
}
ul#nav ul a {
color:#000;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:5px;
text-shadow:#fff 0 0 0;

border-radius:0;
-moz-border-radius:0;
-webkit-border-radius:0;
}
ul#nav ul li:hover>a {
letter-spacing:2px;
}
```

My questoion is. The picture "nav_current.png" is not moving when i switch to a different li. it stays static on the movie li. how can i make it move to my current page? I think i have to input `li:active{background:url("../nav_current.png")` somewhere but i cant seem to figure out where.

(ps: anyone know if u can add pictures in jsfiddle? would be easier to show a complete example)

EDIT: I added the picture i want to move whenever i go on "tv shows" or "donation" etc. http://jsfiddle.net/rae7Ldbg/

Comment: Guess you can add pictures when using absolute urls beginning with http://...

Comment: you can add pictures by uploading them somewhere else and inserting the url. For placeholders you can use http://placehold.it/ or https://placekitten.com/

Comment: this is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kadb1d3s/6/)  with image..

Comment: Do you want to do this only with css? because a js may solve your problem

Comment: pref. yes. as i barely had the basics of JS and even less understanding of it. So unless you want to babysit me through your JS solution incl. explanation (and how to link it from an JS file as i have to look that up otherwise) i would recommend a CSS only solution =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i told you on the comments you can achive this with js and using jquery , for that you will need to add a link to the jquery library on the head of the html .

the difference between the other answer and mine is that , when you press a submenu it puts the image in the element too .

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danprat92/rae7Ldbg/2/)

the js you need :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".tag").click(function(){
       $(".tag").removeClass("current");
         if($(this).parent().parent().hasClass("subs")){
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().children("a").addClass("current");  
         }
        else{
            $(this).addClass("current");
        }

    });
});
```

the reference to the jquery lib

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sound of it is great but using your fiddle, nothing is added in the sub menu (neither on action nor grimm etc.)

Comment: i meant on the parent of that sub. for example if you hit comedy the movies menu will have the image (it would be useless adding it on the submenu element because it will be hidden all the time)

Comment: alright now i get it. yours looks cleaner than the otherone's. Guess its time to get my nose more into js and jqueries. Thanks for the help. Accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can do it witj js / jquery. I dont know a pure html-css solution.

Basically you add a `.active` class on clicked link. First remove `.active` class, then add to the one that is clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/rae7Ldbg/1/

reference: [How to add class (active) on specific "li" on user click with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111946/how-to-add-class-active-on-specific-li-on-user-click-with-jquery)