# How to Keep a tab/li active using JavaScript after a page refresh or loading another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to shift `class="active"` to current tab that i have opened.

**Ex:** If I am in dashboard page, as the class of `<li>` was already set to active. If I entered into another page like profile, now I want to shift that `class=active` from dashboard to profile.

```
<ul class="nav sidebar-menu">
   <li class="active">
      <a href="dashboard.php">
         <span class="sidebar-title">Dashboard</span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="profile.php">
         <span class="sidebar-title">Profile</span>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111946/how-to-add-class-active-on-specific-li-on-user-click-with-jquery

Comment: i had tried it but after loading another page, its not shifting @The Guest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to highlight an menu item based on the actual url?

It could be done with javascript's [`location` object](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-window-location).

You can get each part of the actual url as follow. For this link `http://example.com/index.php` it would be:

- `location.protocol` = *http:*
- `location.host` = *example.com*
- `location.pathname` = */index.php*

For the OP example, you could simply use `location.pathname`:

```
// get the actual pathname:
var path = location.pathname;
// filter menu items to find one that has anchor tag with matching href:
$('.sidebar-menu li').filter(function(){
    return '/' + $('a', this).attr('href') === path;
// add class active to the item:
}).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it with cookies.
there for i suggest that plugin

[github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

there you can

set a cookie like :

```
$.cookie("test", 1);
```

delete a cookie like:

```
$.removeCookie("test");
```

and get the value of the cookie like:

```
var cookieValue = $.cookie("test");
```

so when your button is clicked you can say

```
$('.class').on('click', function(){
    var yourClass = $(this).attr("class"); // the class which should get active
    $.cookie('activeClass', yourClass);
});
```

and on ready of each page

you can do:

```
function checkCookie(){
    var cookieValue = $.cookie('activeClass');
    if(cookieValue.length > 0){
        $(cookieValue).addClass('active');
        $.removeCookie("activeClass");
    }
}
```

did not try it on myself. hope it works... at least you know how to do it :).

ah, and the user of course needs to have cookies activated!

greetings timmi