# Drop down menu won't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a menu that has two items "what's new" and "categories" when a user clicks categories there are supposed to be a ton of sub categories that drop down. However I can't figure out how to get them to drop down. Does anyone have any solutions? Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/v3ftk7t0/

```html
<div class='shop-sidebar'>
    <ul class='shop-nav'>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">What's New</a></li>
        <li class='w-sub' data-id='shop-categories'>
            <svg class='s_arrow_down'><use xlink:href="#s_arrow_down"></use></svg>
            Categories
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">All</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="active">Category 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">All</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Category 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Category 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Category 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Category 4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Category 5</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Category 6</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Category 7</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Category 8</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Category 9</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="active">Category 2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">All</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Category 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Category 2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="active">Category 3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">All</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Sub Category 1</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```css
.shop-sidebar {
    width: 30%;
    width: calc(295px);
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 65px;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-family: 'maison',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul.shop-nav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul.shop-nav li.active, ul.shop-nav li:hover {
    color: #000;
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
}
ul.shop-nav li {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px 20px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
ul.shop-nav li.active a {
    color: #000;
}
ul.shop-nav a {
    color: #000;
}
ul.shop-nav li.active, ul.shop-nav li:hover {
    color: #000;
    opacity: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
}
ul.shop-nav li svg {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    fill: #000;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    float: right;
}
ul.shop-nav li ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 12px 0 0;
}
ul.shop-nav li ul li {
    color: #000;
    border: 0 !important;
    font-family: 'maison',sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
ul.shop-nav li ul ul {
    margin-left: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have the way, I've removed all what i didnt need, you will be able to add it again. Just click on Categories and enjoy!!!

```css
.shop-sidebar {
 width: 30%;
 width: calc(295px);
 display: inline-block;
 padding-right: 65px;
 vertical-align: top;
 font-family: 'maison',sans-serif;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: #000;
 letter-spacing: 1.5px;
 line-height: 18px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul.shop-nav {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
ul.shop-nav li.active, ul.shop-nav li:hover {
 color: #000;
 opacity: 1;
 font-weight: bold;
}
ul.shop-nav li {
 transition: all 0.3s;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 18px 20px;
 background-color: #f8f8f8;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
}
ul.shop-nav li.active a {
 color: #000;
}
ul.shop-nav a {
 color: #000;
}
ul.shop-nav li.active, ul.shop-nav li:hover {
 color: #000;
 opacity: 1;
 font-weight: bold;
}
ul.shop-nav li svg {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 vertical-align: text-bottom;
 fill: #000;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 float: right;
}
ul.shop-nav li ul {
 display: none;
 list-style: none;
 padding-left: 0;
 margin: 12px 0 0;
}
ul.shop-nav li ul li {
 color: #000;
 border: 0 !important;
 font-family: 'maison',sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 letter-spacing: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-transform: none;
 margin-bottom: 12px;
}
ul.shop-nav li ul ul {
 margin-left: 16px;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

#subList, #subListCategory1 {
  display: none;
}

#categories:checked ~ #subList {
  display: block;
}

#category1:checked ~ #subListCategory1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='shop-sidebar'>
  <ul class='shop-nav'>
 <li class="active"><a href="#">What's New</a></li>
 <li class='w-sub' data-id='shop-categories'>
   <svg class='s_arrow_down'><use xlink:href="#s_arrow_down"></use></svg>
   <input type="checkbox" id="categories" />
   <label id="label" for="categories">Categories</label>
   <ul id="subList">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="all" />
    <label id="allLabel" for="all">All</label>
  </li>
  <input type="checkbox" id="category1" />
  <label id="category1Label" for="category1">Category 1</label>
  <ul id="subListCategory1">
    <li>
   <a href="#">All</a>
    </li>
    <li>
   <a href="#">      Sub Category 1       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
   <a href="#">      Sub Category 2       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
   <a href="#">      Sub Category 3       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
   <a href="#">      Sub Category 4       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
   <a href="#">      Sub Category 5       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
   <a href="#">      Sub Category 6       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
   <a href="#">      Sub Category 7       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
   <a href="#">      Sub Category 8       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
   <a href="#">      Sub Category 9       </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="active">
       Category 1     </a>


  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="active">
       Category 2     </a>

    <ul>


   <li>
     <a href="#">
        All
       </a>
   </li>

   <li>
     <a href="#">      Sub Category 1       </a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="#">      Sub Category 2       </a>
   </li>
    </ul>

  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="active">
       Category 3     </a>

    <ul>


   <li>
     <a href="#">
        All
       </a>
   </li>

   <li>
     <a href="#">      Sub Category 1       </a>
   </li>
    </ul>

  </li>

   </ul>
 </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Edit: css classes added again.

[Here](http://codepen.io/facundo_larocca/pen/Ndxbox) the complete fiddle.

Comment: Unfortunately, this code did not work. The "categories" is not clickable.

Comment: Did you click on categories? Maybe what you want to have the click on the whole list element, isnt it? Tell me and I will rewrite it

Comment: I must have had an error when I originally checked it. It now works at pulling down the submenu when I click categories. However now the categories within don't pull down their subcategories when you click them.

Comment: Of course, you have to apply the same technique to all of them, basically use a checkbox and a label for all those sublist element which should be toggled.!!!

Comment: I added one example with one submenu, click on categories and then in Category 1. Let me know if it is what you are looking for. Thanks

Comment: Would you mind helping me set up the other submenus?  I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Done!! Take a look at the end.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I have one last question if your willing to help, is there a way that if you click on a new category that the other categories would close. So there will only be one category menu open at a time. (for example if category 1 was open and then someone clicked category 2 the category 1 menu would close)

Comment: Yes, replace checkboxes for radiobuttons, taht s all. Because radiobuttons have thar behavior by default. You dont need to add anything else. But this is by your own this time my friend!

Answer (score -1):

Add this css:

```
ul.shop-nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

This will do the following:

When you hover over the ul.shop-nav li element you set the ul nested inside to display.

Comment: Thanks! However the menu shows on hover, and not on click. I want it to the sub menu to only show if you click categories.

Comment: My bad, for click events you should use Javascript or jQuery.
Here is a link on how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111946/how-to-add-class-active-on-specific-li-on-user-click-with-jquery 
If you need help with this, please let me know, I'm glad to help.

Comment: Add an id to where your class "w-sub" is, then add this jQeury code:

`<script>
$( "#idHere" ).click(function() {
  $('#idHere ul').css('display', 'block');
});
</script>`

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)